# Extracting Independent variables List from a mlogit object

Tags: r, mlogit

I am using following package:

```
library(mlogit)
```

My data is prepared as follows

```
data(CollegeDistance, package="AER")
testdata <- CollegeDistance
testdata$Dist[testdata$distance<0.4] <- 1
testdata$Dist[testdata$distance<1 & testdata$distance>=0.4] <- 2
testdata$Dist[testdata$distance<2.5 & testdata$distance>=1] <- 3
testdata$Dist[testdata$distance>=2.5] <- 4
```

And here is my model

```
testmodel <- mlogit(as.formula(Dist ~ 1|urban + unemp + tuition|1), testdata, shape='wide', choice='Dist')
```

Now when I run following code the result is weird

```
as.character(attr(testmodel$formula, 'rhs')[[2]])

> as.character(attr(testmodel$formula, 'rhs')[[2]])
[1] "+"             "urban + unemp" "tuition"
```

What I expect is something like:

```
chr [1:3] "urban" "unemp" "tuition"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `all.vars` instead

```
all.vars(testmodel$formula) # return all the variables 
## "Dist"    "urban"   "unemp"   "tuition"
all.vars(testmodel$formula)[-1] # to remove the dependent variable
[1] "urban"   "unemp"   "tuition"
```

and with the function you have used

```
all.vars(attr(testmodel$formula, 'rhs')[[2]])
## [1] "urban"   "unemp"   "tuition"
```